# Qt default menu

Tags: qt

I need to add the regular menu present in applications that includes (file, setup, help, ... ). Is there a default structure that i can include to do this, or should i add it manually through buttons and stack structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a menu you can just use the [QMenuBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QMenuBar.html), and put QMenu/QAction objects on it.

If you have a QMainWindow its method menuBar() will create a menu in the main window.

You could also edit it in the designer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add them manually, there is no "default structure".

[QMenuBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QMenuBar.html)